# scala 3 inlining fails a very simple example

Tags: scala, scala-macros, scala-3

I'm exploring the possibilities of scala3's inlining. I've made up a simple example where I want a validation method constructing a sealed class to be applied at compile time:

```scala
import scala.compiletime.{ error, codeOf }

sealed abstract class OneOrTwo(val code: String)

object OneOrTwo {

    case object One extends OneOrTwo("one")
    case object Two extends OneOrTwo("two")

    def from(s: String): Option[OneOrTwo] = 
        s match {
            case One.code => Some(One)
            case Two.code => Some(Two)
            case _ => None
        }

    inline def inlinedFrom1(s: String): OneOrTwo = {
        inline s match {
            case "one" => One
            case "two" => Two
            case _ => error("can't make a OneOrTwo out of " + codeOf(s))
        } 
    }

    val test1 = OneOrTwo.inlinedFrom1("one") // compiles 
    val test12 = OneOrTwo.inlinedFrom1("three") // doesn't compile as expected -> can't make a OneOrTwo out of "three"
}
```

So far, so good. But what I really want is to be able to re-use the `from` function within the inlined one. Here's me trying:

```scala
    // this goes in the OneOrTwo companion object as well

    inline def inlinedFrom2(s: String): OneOrTwo = {
        from(s).getOrElse(error("can't make a OneOrTwo out of " + codeOf(s)))
    }

    inline def inlinedFrom3(s: String): OneOrTwo = {
        s match {
            case One.code => One
            case Two.code => Two
            case _ => error("can't make a OneOrTwo out of " + codeOf(s))
        }
    }

    
    val test2 = OneOrTwo.inlinedFrom2("one") // doesn't compile -> can't make a OneOrTwo out of "one"
    val test3 = OneOrTwo.inlinedFrom3("one") // doesn't compile -> can't make a OneOrTwo out of "one"
```

`inlinedFrom3` is a generalisation to show that if I match on the objects' code directly, the compiler doesn't see that they are the same as the input string and takes the wrong branch.

What I'd like to understand is why `inlinedFrom3` doesn't work and whether there is a way to make it work.

Note: I'm using scala 3.0.0-RC2

Comment: Should the parameter `s` not also be `inline`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Good question,

First of all, consider that inlining is a way to perform meta-programming at compile time in Scala (as you have done in your example).

To get bet on your problem, here the compiler doesn't understand  that `One.code` is of type `"one"`.
Indeed, if you try to print `One.code`, the compiler output is:

```
OneOrTwo.One.code
```

and not

```
"one"
```

But wait, why? Because the compiler can't infer anything about the One.code at compile time. To give the missing information to the compiler you can:

- specify the singleton string type

```
sealed trait OneOrTwo {
  val code: String
}

object OneOrTwo {
    case object One extends OneOrTwo {
      override val code : "one" = "one" 
    }
    case object Two extends OneOrTwo {
      override val code : "two" = "two"
    }
}
```

- inline `val` definition

```
sealed trait OneOrTwo {
  val code: String
}

object OneOrTwo {
    case object One extends OneOrTwo {
      override inline val code = "one" 
    }
    case object Two extends OneOrTwo {
      override inline val code = "two"
    }
}
```

Even with this modification, your code continues to fail in the compilation. It is caused by the match clause not inlined. Indeed, as mentioned [here](https://dl-acm-org.ezproxy.unibo.it/doi/pdf/10.1145/3426426.3428486.),  *the error method provides a way to emit custom error messages. The error will be emitted if a call to error is inlined and not eliminated as a dead branch.*
So if you put `error(...)` in a code not inlined, an error will be always thrown.
For example, this code:

```
if(false) { error("thrown..") } { }
```

produces a compilation error.

Finally, to solve your problem, you need to inline your match clause:

```
inline def inlinedFrom3(s: String): OneOrTwo = {
   inline s match {
       case One.code => One
       case Two.code => Two
       case _ => error("can't make a OneOrTwo out of " + codeOf(s))
   }
}
```

The compilation (for `inlinedFrom3`) succeeded. `inlineFrom2` continues to fail due to the problem aforementioned.

Comment: thanks @gianluca-aguzzi!, It does help somewhat; but it also raises more questions: 1) why do I need to inline the match for `inlineFrom3` to work?, 2) why doesn't `inlinedFrom2` work after the change? and 3) why can the compiler work out the comparison between a string literal and a string in the original `from` and not in `inlineFrom3`?

Comment: First of all, consider that inline is a way to perform meta-programming in Scala [Reference](https://dl-acm-org.ezproxy.unibo.it/doi/pdf/10.1145/3426426.3428486.).
For 1, the reason why you need to inline match is the same for you inlined the first version: you need to perform some compile-time check, namely a constant folded in its condition to eliminate one of the branches. To do so, you need to perform inlining. Indeed, if you remove inline from your first version, the compilation fails. It is tricky but is similar to old macro expansion, I don't know if you are used to using them.

Comment: For 2, it doesn't work because  `getOrElse`  is not inlined and, when the compiler goes through that piece of code, it evals the expression in the `getOrElse` and then raise the error. Consider that an error method provides a way to emit custom error messages. The error will be emitted if a call to error is inlined and not eliminated as a dead branch..

Comment: For the last question,  if the type is not explicit, the compiler can't do anything at compile time. You can also use inlining again, for example:
`override inline val code = "one" ` 
in this way, there is no need to specify the type. Indeed, the string literal will be put in place instead of the variable reference.
I hope I was clear and to have given you the references to look into it further.

Comment: thanks a lot @gianluca-aguzzi! I had clearly missed some important things about inlining, but it's much clearer now. This point especially really hit home: "The error will be emitted if a call to error is inlined and not eliminated as a dead branch".

Comment: @gianlucaaguzzi Could you add your comments to your answer? They'd be pretty helpful